# (Optim) Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Tags: r, optimization, input

In a larger optimization task, i'm stuck at a point where I need to input a list into `optim`. However, when within the list there is a vector, I get the error

(list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Below there's an reproducible example and the error source is in the `butter` line. Splitting it into scalars makes the code work, but what I really want to is a list like `init_param` (with `butter` being a vector).

```
fun = function(param_list){

  x2 = param_list[["x2"]]
  bread = param_list[["bread"]]
  x3 = param_list[["x3"]]
  butter = param_list[["butter"]]

  sum(
    (bread - 3)^2, (x2-4)^2, (x3-125)^2, (butter[1])^2, (butter[2])^2
    )
}

init_param = list(x3 = -1, bread = 50, x2 = 120, butter = c(1,2))

optim(par = init_param, fn = fun)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments for `par` need to be scalar, so your `butter` is throwing things off.

One way to remedy this is to break out the vector into scalars. (I am preserving your ultimate `sum` formula, though this remedy could easily change things in different ways to get the same result.)

```r
fun = function(param_list){

  x2 = param_list[["x2"]]
  bread = param_list[["bread"]]
  x3 = param_list[["x3"]]
  butter = c(param_list[["butter1"]], param_list[["butter2"]])

  sum(
    (bread - 3)^2, (x2-4)^2, (x3-125)^2, (butter[1])^2, (butter[2])^2
    )
}
init_param = list(x3 = -1, bread = 50, x2 = 120, butter1 = 1, butter2 = 2)

optim(par = init_param, fn = fun)
# $par
#            x3         bread            x2       butter1       butter2 
# 124.995189738   2.998084514   3.997427390   0.004101379  -0.005390156 
# $value
# [1] 7.930112e-05
# $counts
# function gradient 
#      262       NA 
# $convergence
# [1] 0
# $message
# NULL
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Although it makes optim run, what I really want is to input `butter` as a vector, not a scalar, and I'm not sure it's possible.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, and while it would be nice if it accepted a nested object like that, it does not. If your input parameters are of a fixed length, then you're going to have to unlist them, either manually (as in my answer) or as @ravic_'s answer. If the number of parameters changes, then I suspect you might have to rethink your use of `optim`.

Comment: Well I kinda knew that it just wasn't possible, just asked to get this doubt of me. Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

The `optim` function requires the input to be a simple vector. You can restructure your code using `unlist` to explicitly create the vector from what you have, and then adjust your function and surrounding code.

```
init_param = list(x3 = -1, bread = 50, x2 = 120, butter = c(1,2))
param_vector <- unlist(init_param)
param_vector
#>      x3   bread      x2 butter1 butter2 
#>      -1      50     120       1       2
```

Comment: Sure it works (and i'm using this strategy for now), but I want to input in a list format, not a vector.